# How to uninstall Scangear

Tags: drivers, wireless

I installed Scangear to access my Canon Mx922 scanner(only way I could recognize it was wirelessly) cups recognized the printer fine. Ubuntu now wants to upgrade Scangear. During upgrades Scangear wants to upgrade but fails every time saying unable to delete old files. I would like to uninstall Scangear since I no longer need to access the Mx922 wirelessly. How can I uninstall Scangear?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: I used last year simple-scan as the app.

Answer (score 0):

Canon's ScanGear package is called `scangearmp2`, so removing it is a simple matter of doing this:

0. Open a Terminal
1. Type:

   ```
   sudo apt remove --purge scangearmp2
   ```

That's all